# How to set {base_url} in Magento crosses the servers (which are set the code and db)

Tags: magento

In Magento, at `from core_config_data` table, at the moment, I see that we must set `base_url` ip is `192.168.1.100`.

If I move it into a another computer it will not work. Why I need to do this? Cause our developers code at their local and commit source code to another server (ip is 192.168.1.113, for example) to automatically build.

So, my question is how to cross server with Magento?

Please, see the below table if you need to have the context.

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data;
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                                                | value
+-----------+---------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------
|         1 | default |        0 | web/seo/use_rewrites                                | 0
|         2 | default |        0 | admin/dashboard/enable_charts                       | 1
|         3 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url                               | http://192.168.1.100/
|         4 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url                                 | http://192.168.1.100/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new view of your store and assign to it a new base_url. So:

1. Create a new store view on System » Manage Stores
2. Go to System » Configuration and select the new store view
3. On General » Web you can change the base_url

That's all. Be sure that all your products and other things are available for all the store views (by default, it is that way).

Comment: Hell @PauGNU, i don't think it works. Let me explain more here: after you move source and import db). If we don't change anything form DB. How we can open the admin page?

Comment: I can't test it now. But I'll try if it's possible to access to the admin page from a store view with a different base_url.

Comment: Hi, I love you so much @PauGNU... Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Hi again. Here is what I've tried: created two view stores, each one with its own URL. I could access the admin just adding /admin to both configured url. So... it works for me. You should try.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could solve it with an entry in your hosts file on the developer machines.  Instead of using the IP in the URL, you use a FQDN and add that FQDN into the developer's hosts file with either their local IP address or the loopback IP address.

Comment: @Saferite: I don't know what is FQDN? Update: I've searched now I got it. I don't think it's a good idea. I need that it will work normally. You know, if you write a website with relative path, you don't get this problem when you move it to others.

Comment: Not sure why it woudln't work out.  I use it all the time for local dev VMs that get passed around. In any case, it was just a suggestion. :)